# Some parts of material appear darker than it should be

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

I don't know why Eevee works well, but Cycles creates weird patches in the material and I don't know what to do.

[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have faces that's located at the same position. Take a look at example. Here is the default cube in cycles:

[image]

Nothing special. Now I duplicate the cube and move it in x direction, while Y and Z remains unchanged.

[image]

As you see, there is a black where faces overlaps.

Now I will move cube so that Y ans Z positions will be different:

[image]

This also apples on faces in the same objects. So any time then you will have overlapping faces, you will get this problem.