# Same material is giving different shades in renderd view

Tags: materials, shaders, lighting

I am having a strange problem and am unable to fix it. I am using the same material on two different parts of the car body but one material is showing up lighter than the other. the material looks fine in material preview but problem in rendered view.  I have checked the normal, face orientation, duplication, and modifiers, and everything seems right. can anyone help me understand what am I doing wrong here? the only thing I can notice is light and dark blue in face orientation mode but do not know what this is and how to fix it.

[image] [image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file, at least 2 parts of the car: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hard to tell just from those images what is wrong. As @moonboots commented, sharing your file would be best. At least a screenshot of the material would have been nice to have a look at it as well, but I guess the mesh itself might be more insightful.

Comment: yes, I am sharing it. thank you

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=QG8YNOpk" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/QG8YNOpk/)

Comment: the link to the file is

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=QG8YNOpk" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/QG8YNOpk/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an array modifier with zero offset:

[image]

This leads to overlapping geometry. I've already posted an answer about overlapping geometry here:

[Some parts of material appear darker than it should be](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267400/blender-problem-with-the-material/267403#267403)

Comment: yes, thank you. I wonder how I missed it. been looking at this problem for days