# Why is my material changing in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image: EEVEE]

[image: cycles]

On the robe it changes in cycles. why? its just a normal image texture. I Don't understand why it is different. I was having some issues with the displacement on the ground but i fixed it but the clothes are still a different color. What would cause this?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kuzyaujep8ebd3c/Landscape_free_files.blend?dl=0

Comment: pls check this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123724/eevee-and-cycles-render-lighting-differences

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some parts of material appear darker than it should be](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267400/some-parts-of-material-appear-darker-than-it-should-be)